# Magento productpage color choice customization

Tags: magento-1.9

I made 2 magento (1.9.2.3) webshop to test a few thing... and at the productpage, in the section where I have to choose the product color what I want, there are 2 type of filed I can set in admin: or a dropdown menu (select with options), or simple buttons.

Using the same template at both demo website, somehow at the first webshop that section is a dropdown, and at the other, the section is simple buttons, and I don't know how I did this, because in the admin both settings are the same.

So I want to use the buttons, but now I don't know exactly how can I set it as default?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code you already have? It's very difficult to help with little context, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, meanwhile already i got the solution:
system -> configuration -> catalog -> configurable swatches ->general setting
And here I had to allow this function, and choose the necessary product attributes